# Pandas groupby to get a total of a column by each comma separated value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

From the given sample dataset below, I want to draw a clustered bar chart showing total revenue by each feature for every year

```
-------------------------------
Year  Product Feature   Revenue
-------------------------------
2012  P1      a,d,e     98
2016  P2      a,b,c     167
2014  P3      d,e       120
2014  P4      a,c       144
2016  P5      b,c,d     156
2016  P6      e,a       107
```

The data to draw the chart could be:

```
---------------------------------
Year | Feature_wise_total_revenue
---------------------------------
       a    b    c     d     e
2012   98   0    0     98    98
2014   144  0    140   120   120
2016   274  323  323   156   107
```

Please help to get the code for the total revenue by each feature for every year from the sample dataset.

Comment: _Please help to get the code for the total revenue by each feature for every year from the sample dataset._ Do you have an actual, specific question? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: Dear @AMC, 
it would have been a longer question to explain my actual and specific question. To make it simple I converted my actual problem to the simple problem to ask the solution. I tried to save the time of the community through this approach.

Also I mentioned my specific problem in the question statement "Pandas groupby to get a total of a column by each comma separated value in another column"

However your point noted for future queries. Thanks

Comment: _To make it simple I converted my actual problem to the simple problem to ask the solution._ As a result there is almost no chance that this question will ever benefit anyone else, it’s just noise. Never mind the fact that it arguable does not fit the requirements/standards of SO. Also I mentioned my specific problem_ No, that is the goal/objective, not the problem/obstacle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, using the string accessor, `.str`, and `split` with `explode`. The `groupby` and `sum` with `unstack`:

```
df.assign(Feature=df['Feature'].str.split(',')).explode('Feature')\
  .groupby(['Year','Feature'])['Revenue'].sum().unstack(1).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
Feature      a      b      c      d      e
Year                                      
2012      98.0    0.0    0.0   98.0   98.0
2014     144.0    0.0  144.0  120.0  120.0
2016     274.0  323.0  323.0  156.0  107.0
```

Plotting:

```
df_out.plot.bar()
```

[image]